# Derby/Intellij java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'ALCOHOL' does not exist

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

Tried setting up a simple embedded Derby Database via IntelliJ. When trying to access the tables from jdbc I get errors saying the tables do not exist. When I type in the terminal for the database the same query I get data unlike jdbc.

[image: One thousand words]

Method

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int wob = 0;
        ResultSet rset;
        Statement stmt;

        String qry = "SELECT * FROM ALCOHOL WHERE ALCOHOL.ALCOHOL_TYPE = ";

        do{
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("1: For Malt Beverages");
            System.out.println("2: For Wine");
            System.out.println("");
            wob = input.nextInt();
        }while(wob != 1 && wob != 2);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(qry + wob);

        System.out.println(" ID|                     Name|               BrandName |APPELLATION |      Type");
        System.out.println("---|-------------------------|-------------------------|------------|----------");

        while(rset.next()){
            String ID = String.format("%1$"+3+ "s", rset.getString("AID"));
            String name = String.format("%1$"+25+ "s", rset.getString("NAME"));
            String brandname = String.format("%1$"+25+ "s", rset.getString("BRAND_NAME"));
            String app = String.format("%1$"+22+ "s", rset.getString("APPELLATION"));
            String type = String.format("%1$"+10+ "s", rset.getString("ALCOHOL_TYPE"));
            System.out.println(ID + "|" + name + "|" + brandname + "|" + app + "|" + type);
        }
        System.out.println("---|-------------------------|-------------------------|------------|----------");

        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
        input.close();
```

Trace:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'ALCOHOL' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at Main.search(Main.java:89)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'ALCOHOL' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Your database name is unqualified, which means it is created in the *current directory*. Your Java program and your terminal are likely not using the same current directory. Since your program expects tables to already exist, remove `;create=true`, so it will fail early if it doesn't exist. Then qualify the database file in both program and terminal, or ensure both use the same current directory.

Comment: um how do i qualify them

Answer (score 0):

Firstly table names are case-sensitive, please do a quick check on the same
Secondly, if you are using the right table name for your query, you need to change it to add the schema details as well.

This is one such example, how you could use a simple SELECT query.

```
SELECT * FROM {schema}."{tablename}"
```

If you want to translate the above query into JAVA, you might have to use this and it should work.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM {schema}.\"ALCOHOL\"";
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: unfortunately no. same response

Comment: Table names are only case sensitive if they were created using double quotes. `alcohol` and `ALCOHOL` are both the same name. However `"alcholo"` and `"ALCOHOL"` are not.